# Comparing Two Arrays resulting into Third Array

Tags: python

I have two Arrays:

```
firstArray=[['AF','AFGHANISTAN'],['AL','ALBANIA'],['DZ','ALGERIA'],['AS','AMERICAN SAMOA']]
secondArray=[[1,'AFGHANISTAN'],[3,'AMERICAN SAMOA']]
```

So I just need an Array which is like

```
thirdArray=[[1,'AF'],[3,'AS']]
```

I tried `any(e[1] == firstArray[i][1] for e in secondArray)`
It returned me True and false if second element of both array matches. but i don't know how to build the third array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, convert `firstArray` into a dict with the country as the key and abbreviation as the value, then just look up the abbreviation for each country in `secondArray` using a list comprehension:

```
abbrevDict = {country: abbrev for abbrev, country in firstArray}
thirdArray = [[key, abbrevDict[country]] for key, country in secondArray]
```

If you are on a Python version without dict comprehensions (2.6 and below) you can use the following to create `abbrevDict`:

```
abbrevDict = dict((country, abbrev) for abbrev, country in firstArray)
```

Or the more concise but less readable:

```
abbrevDict = dict(map(reversed, firstArray))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to store them into dictionaries:

```
firstDictionary = {key:value for value, key in firstArray}
# in older versions of Python:
# firstDictionary = dict((key, value) for value, key in firstArray)
```

then you could get the 3rd array simply by dictionary look-up:

```
thirdArray = [[value, firstDictionary[key]] for value, key in secondArray]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interim `dict` as a lookup:

```
firstArray=[['AF','AFGHANISTAN'],['AL','ALBANIA'],['DZ','ALGERIA'],['AS','AMERICAN SAMOA']]
secondArray=[[1,'AFGHANISTAN'],[3,'AMERICAN SAMOA']]

lookup = {snd:fst for fst, snd in firstArray}
thirdArray = [[n, lookup[name]] for n, name in secondArray]
```

Answer (score 0):

If a dictionary would do, there is a special purpose Counter dictionary for exactly this use case.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(firstArray + secondArray)
Counter({['AF','AFGHANISTAN']: 1 ... })
```

Note that the arguments are reversed from what you requested, but that's easily remedied.

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension:

```
In [119]: fa=[['AF','AFGHANISTAN'],['AL','ALBANIA'],['DZ','ALGERIA'],['AS','AMERICAN SAMOA']]

In [120]: sa=[[1,'AFGHANISTAN'],[3,'AMERICAN SAMOA']]

In [121]: [[y[0],x[0]] for x in fa for y in sa if y[1]==x[1]]

Out[121]: [[1, 'AF'], [3, 'AS']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to match data to a key is a dictionary.  You can convert `firstArray` to a dictionary using dict comprehension.

```
firstDict = {x: y for (y, x) in firstArray}
```

You can then iterate over your second array using list comprehension.

```
[[i[0], firstDict[i[1]]] for i in secondArray]
```